Nintex Workflow - Copy an Item - People Picker field
I am currently developing a list for trial requests. One QoL features for the user should be, that they can copy an old trial to avoid double entering a lot of data. The user can chose an old trial id, which than should be copied.
This works well with a 'Retrieve an item' -> Object.Variable 'CopyOfTrial' and "Update items' function.
But when it comes to copying People Picker fields, the 'CopyOfTrial' item contains the People/User Picker information broken up into, ID, Email, DisplayName, Username and not as one 'field value' User.
As this 'field value' User should again be used in a People Picker/'Assign a task to multiple users field' function, these single value don't help me.
Is there a way to copy the 'User' instead of it's ID, Email, DisplayName and Username?
Christian
